# Is there a way to send an embed without any message content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I think its anoying to have to send some message content along with the embed. I know you can use some invisible character like `\u200B` but there will still be an empty line. Is there a way around this or am I just forced to send something, even if its invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in `discord.js` v13, you don't need to send some message content along with the embed. The embed alone can be sent using this:

```js
message.channel.send({
    embeds: [embedname]
})
```

If you want to learn more about the embed, you can go here => [Embeds | discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds)

Comment: In fact, you never had to send message content along with the embed. You only needed at least one of  `embeds` or `content`

Comment: Don't know much about v12 so that's why I wrote it like that. Thanks!